# What is the purpose of the questionnaire on moderator elections?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

When voting on moderator elections, I pay almost no attention to the candidate's questionnaire, I much prefer to concentrate on past knowledge on their interaction with other users, statistics, participation in the site curation and so forth. I thought this was just me, but I came to find out that that may not be the case.

In this year's election, there was a situation where some candidates answers were similar, and it seems that almost no one noticed, [with some exceptions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412356/6865932), note that the linked post is only 2 days old, so apparently it's not just me.

This leads me to think about the usefulness of these questionnaires, candidates tend to answer with some sensible *pro-forma* generic answer which adds little to no reason to vote for the particular candidate. The part I find more useful is the comment section where often the candidates debate with other users, it's more clarifying than the answers themselves, but for some reason, the comment section is removed before the voting starts.

I don't have the answers but surely there must be a way to make the questionnaire more engaging or perhaps replace it with some more interesting mechanisms to get to know the candidate's thoughts.

Also, I don't understand why the comment section is hidden so well after the voting starts.

(The comments are still available, I missed them because they are oddly placed as [Makyen points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412452/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-questionnaire-on-moderator-elections?noredirect=1#comment874676_412452))

Comment: Seems like a continuation of [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412409/4826457)

Comment: @SurajRao I'll be damned, I didn't read that far down, but, yes, it's closely related.

Comment: I also don't pay too much attention to the questionnaire, but this year it was especially useful because of the question you linked about similar answers. This raised issues that would likely not have been noticed without the questionnaire.

Comment: And about your last phrase, there's a discussion about it: [Why are comments disabled in elections once the election phase starts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412363/8839059)

Comment: Personally, I think this is just a symptom of this year's questions being relatively boring, with predictable answers. I usually read the questionnaire answers with great interest, and base my decision primarily on that, but I didn't find them nearly as useful this year because, as you said, most of the candidates were answering them in the same or similar ways.

Comment: @CodyGray *"this year's questions being relatively boring"* - ***this*** year's? I don't recall the questionnaire questions ever being interesting. That said, I don't know what other basis we'd have to decide on when voting for candidates, so it still clearly has purpose.

Comment: The community suggests and votes on the questions in the questionnaire.

Comment: @JeanneDark does it? I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: [2021 Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411988/11682469)

Comment: The issue with this year's copied answers wouldn't have been prevented by having all new questions, for the record. The issue was that one candidate copied other candidates' answers after those other candidates posted them.

Comment: *"candidates tend to answer with some sensible pro-forma generic answer which adds little to no reason to vote for the particular candidate"* - You're right. But if a candidate *does not* give a cookie cutter answer... that might elevate my opinion of them. I do read through the answers (if they are actually provided...), perhaps something pops out that catches me off-guard.

Comment: Comments aren't actually *removed* during the election. The comments are still available under the election's [nomination tab](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13?tab=nomination). While I think the comments *should be* visible on the [election tab](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13?tab=election), it's inaccurate to think that they are gone/unavailable after the election starts. Unfortunately, having them only on the nomination tab does *effectively* hide them from most users.

Comment: @Makyen so they are, I missed that, which reinforces your point *Unfortunately, having them only on the nomination tab does effectively hide them from most users*. It's better than not having them though. Thanks.

Comment: "...interesting mechanisms to get to know the candidate's thoughts..." This is generally difficult. You cannot really know what people think. They could lie.

Comment: *...it seems that almost no one noticed...* No one reported it until 2 days ago. That doesn't necessarily mean no one noticed. We have no idea what voters who don't use Meta thought when they read the questionnaire.

Comment: @Trilarion that's inevitable, it's so in the questionnaire, and will be in any other form.

Comment: @BSMP, that's an assumption of mine, for me it's hard to believe that if many people noticed it would took so long till someone said something.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The purpose is to help the community see something more of the candidate than some raw candidate score. While a lot of them overlap, sometimes they don't in interesting ways. There's more than a few (all deleted) candidacies that fell apart because their questionnaire contained answers that showed that they didn't know a lot about how moderation works in general. One candidate wanted to cast a close vote and see how many joined him in doing the same (moderator votes are binding so your votes close anything upon being cast).

You could cut your teeth moderating a smaller site, but SO is a site where the moderation is done at scale, and there's a lot to do. It's good to know a candidate at least has some grasp of how things *should* work, as opposed to [someone who just wants a diamond next to their name](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69532000/revisions) (community managers removed that nomination). In some ways, the questionnaire is [simply a test to see if you're paying attention](https://youtu.be/NzWNBbY-zSE?t=119).

Comment: "...they didn't know a lot about how moderation works in general...." It's a knowledge test then?

Comment: @trilarion I think that understanding how moderation works is a fair requirement to have. I think an excellent follow up question here is, "How can newer users or veteran users who might be interested in moderation learn how diamond moderation functions on this site?" I'm not sure if there is an answer or FAQ that covers this. I know how *community* moderation works, and some of the additional functions a diamond mod has, but I'm sure I don't know all of what a diamond mod has access to aside from access to all rep-based privileges, binding votes, and the ability to review and act on flags.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest That's a fair question. The two things I would suggest in that vein are 1. Go do some [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review). These require a low amount of rep and give you some idea of what reviewing in general looks like 2. Hang out in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). You'll learn a ton about moderation and sometimes even see diamonds in action (full disclosure: I am a room owner there)

Comment: *because their questionnaire contained answers that showed that they didn't know a lot* Any proof or link? The [link you showed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69532000/revisions) only shows the "About" section of 1 candidate. Was there significant differences between "About" and "Questionnaire" of any candidate, that warrant the existence of questionnaire? Said otherwise, Is there anything significant that we couldn't just find out from  the "About" section? In your link, clearly the "About" section was enough to disqualify the candidate nomination.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest  "How can newer users or veteran users who might be interested in moderation learn how diamond moderation functions on this site?" They don't really need to know this until they are elected and not all are elected. I would expect that they get additional training on the job by their peers afterwards and that there is a handbook somewhere which may or may not be also publicly available. If somebody wants you to work for him/her it's their duty to make sure you know everything you need to know going beyond what is known from normal curating of the content here.

Comment: What is maybe missing is a detailed description of what being a diamond moderator entails. It could be that people apply for the job within these elections without knowing exactly what it will be.

Comment: @Trilarion but if what Machavity says is true, candidates either dropped out or were removed because they didn't understand how moderation works on this site. That doesn't necessarily mean they have no moderation skill; they just may not understand the mod tools of this site. But as it stands it seems this is either a soft or hard barrier to entry and as such this information should be publicly gleaned somehow.

Comment: @Machavity gives some great pointers on how one can become familiarized with some of the inner moderation workings here, especially with the suggesting of lurking around in SOVCR.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Just to be clear here, candidates have never been removed due to not giving quality answers on the questionnaire. Some candidates have chosen to drop out after the community questioned them, either on the nomination or on the questionnaire (which the latter is now merged with the former).

Comment: @Machavity Fair enough, but that still tells me the community wants new mods to be familiar with the moderation process here. I don't see why they would have otherwise dropped out simply because the moderation process here doesn't match what they might have seen/done on other sites. So your suggestions are a fair viewpoint into the inner workings and processes of SO moderation.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest "...they didn't understand how moderation works on this site. That doesn't necessarily mean they have no moderation skill; they just may not understand the mod tools of this site. But as it stands it seems this is either a soft or hard barrier to entry and as such this information should be publicly gleaned somehow..." Fully agree. I personally do not hold insufficient knowledge of inside stuff (that goes beyond normal curation activity) negative against any candidate, but others may. And of course the knowledge should be as public and as well presented as possible.

Answer (score 14):

There is currently an in progress update being implemented with regards to candidate information and interaction. In other words, the current state of the questionnaire -- and more broadly the nomination placard -- is in  [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review).

The team is attempting to convey meaningful data to users not as in touch with the overall community or current meta. If you are reading this, that is probably not you. What you could do is provide some feedback (they probably should have set up a broader announcement for this to be honest) on the metrics and space generated for candidates.

In the set of features being reviewed, they are looking at candidate score, the questionnaire, the space allotted, and the comment section. Clearly nothing was done with regards to the comment section. In an attempt to weigh the candidate score more against actual user knowledge or contribution, the questionnaire was inlined this election, which also gave each candidate much more (albeit discoverable) space.

The results were kind of haphazard, in that the questionnaire can no longer have comments on it. A fairly strong backfire especially when paired with the fact that comments are closed on the main nominations *and* we skipped the primary since there were less than 10 candidates. If comments were retained on the questionnaire, then we wouldn't have had the spectacle of "just ask a question on meta if you want a response" (which has been abysmal).

Going forward, comments clearly need to take a stronger front seat in the process of elections, and the questionnaire itself needs to be separated out again. Inlining it was an okay approach in theory but in practice has failed in several key areas, notably in being able to facilitate discourse between candidates and community (part of the intent was to make it more town hall*ish* but instead it kind of comes across as a billboard now).

Let's not just throw out the questionnaire though. It really wasn't its fault. The design iteration failed, but there is room to fix it. Moreover, we also had very low turnout and engagement. The set of questions put forth as suggestions for the questionnaire were stale, reused, and not as relevant today as they should be; as well, the list of candidates was short and lacking any 6 figure contributors.

Answer (score 9):

I also value my own observations of the candidates over time more than I value their questionnaire responses, but I do still think the questionnaire is useful for a couple of reasons.

First, not everyone who can vote has been here that long, so not everyone can rely on their past knowledge of the candidates. Even if the questions are fairly generic, the questionnaire gives the candidates an opportunity to let people get to know them a little bit. If you aren't familiar with someone, their responses can give you an idea of their personality and their ability to express themselves in writing, as well as their individual takes on the various aspects of moderation covered by the questions. Even if you would expect that everyone has basically the same idea about something, someone may have a unique take on some detail of it that you particularly like or dislike.

Second is something that might not have occurred to me until this time around. Rather than seeing a candidate's unique responses to the questions, apparently it's also important to simply see how much effort they appear to have put into their nomination. No offense intended to anyone by saying this, and I certainly don't mean to sound like I'm judging anyone myself, but based on what I've read here the past couple of days, there is definitely a perception associated with this that is meaningful to people.

Answer (score 1):

It's a form of the candidates answering to the public and the purpose is for the public to get insights into the candidates by talking with them.

In principle everyone can ask any question to every candidate in the comment thread below the nomination, but there is never enough time and space for that. Anyway, many interesting questions would probably be the same for all the candidates and asking exactly the same questions in exactly the same form offers the ability to compare answers (well the candidates seem to do that do, maybe there should be a fixed date until when they hand in their answers instead of publishing nominations as they come in). That's why the questionnaire was invented (I guess). Additional questions you might have, you can still ask in the comments section, but it's really very much hidden unfortunately.

Does it fulfill its purpose, i.e. does it give many insights? A few yes, but difficult to say how many. The most important question is surely "Why do you want to do this job?" and is already answered in the nomination post. All the other questions seem to revolve around role playing some standard troubleshooting cases (like in an assessment center) or seem to be knowledge questions and while it's good to know if a candidate does indeed know how to curate, you would probably not expect him/her to know how to moderate before being a moderator (and once you have the job, hopefully there is a handbook somewhere). The useful answers for me in the past were mostly about kind of what the general approach to moderation should be, i.e. let candidates tell their opinion about how the site should be moderated. I voted then for the candidate whose approach I could identify the most with. But then again, candidates can anticipate that and just state what they think most people might want to hear. At the very least they will probably withhold any opinion that they fear may not be well received and that's why one also has to read between the lines to extract useful information.