# Congratulations, Zoe

Tags: discussion, meta, moderator-election

> **Moderator note:** This is a *highly unusual* Meta post, but it follows [unique circumstances](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412472/candidate-changes-in-2021-moderator-election-review-your-ballot) in general.  Please do not close or delete this post. Moderators will reverse either action.

Congratulations, Zoe.

I follow those who deserve to be followed.

Dharman, please accept my apologies. You deserved to become a moderator, but unfortunately failed.

Catija sent me an admin message with a cc to all mods. I deserve to be suspended from SO/SE. If you want to suspend me, please do so without CC.

I am late to answer due to electricity fails.

Comment: I just would like to agree with Shree about Dharman, I see him like everyday when reviewing because he edit so much post. Can we create a third mod place ? :)

Comment: Glad you are back Shree! Big up to you for owning. Many were worried about you. I hope everyone can forgive for what has had happened. Mistakes are only stepping stones to become a better version of yourself. People learn, change and become a better version of themselves, I would never hold this against you. Actions matter do the great work you already do. Maybe not my place but I suggest using Grammarly or Google Translate to write messages like you would in your native language. But yes some of it is lost in translation but it is what it is.

Comment: Shree, I'm really pleased you're back online. 

I don't think we've interacted on the site but I've personally benefitted from some of your contributions and even though I wasn't eligible to vote in the election I did follow it quite closely. Despite everything that happened I don't think anyone holds anything personal against you for what happened and I really hope you decide to stick around and continue contributing!

Comment: I thought I posted a comment, but it seems to have gotten lost in my messy tabs earlier, so let's try again: thanks - and welcome back, Shree! I also do hope you run again next time, or later for that matter, in spite of stuff:tm: getting a bit complicated this election. But until then, I do hope to see you around SOBotics

Comment: It's good to see you back, Shree.  I appreciate this post and I personally forgive you on this one.  It's true, vandals are suspended (on MSE a few days ago one was given a time-out for a single) instance, but I think the mods mitigated the sentence because of what you've done (and hopefully will continue to do) for S.O., and because of the circumstances.  Also, most vandals don't apologize and say they deserve to be suspended.  Come back to SOBotics; see if you can reach a 6-digit number of helpful flags.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412356/two-candidates-in-the-moderator-election-have-given-nearly-identical-answers-to/412364#412364 this appears to be the context for the post

Comment: Language barrier. Maybe if the OP posted in his native language and someone else could translate it there would be less confusion. Nevertheless, I sense sincere regret and a desire to make amends.

Comment: Comments removed. We are allowing the post to remain (see edit above). Please focus on the topic at hand (Shree or the election), and not if this belongs on Meta. Thanks.

Comment: Just a small note, regarding your request for Catija to not CC other mods should you be suspended: That's not something they chose to do, or can choose not to do. All mods are always CC'd on all moderator messages, whether or not a suspension is involved. We cannot turn this on or off, it just happens.

Comment: I can't speak for others (although I can imagine many feel the way I do) but I personally forgive you and hope to see your run again in the future. Please be sure to answer any future questionnaires from the heart, in your own words, because it's the content that counts more than presentation. Keep up the good work and all the best!

Comment: @Shree I greet the god within you. Hale Weather Shree.

Comment: This question seems unpopular because of it's score, but it's actually +113/-55

Comment: Y'all can see the comment the moderators prepended the post with.  Why are you still voting to close it?  You're making more work where none needs to be made.

Comment: @Ollie Because in spite of there being an in your face message, some people still don't get the message. Welcome to the internet

Comment: @Zoe *Yeeessss...* but we can still ask for an explanation.  Just the same way some people ask why someone decided to post a hardware question to MSE instead of SU.

Answer (score 131):

Shree! Glad to see you're OK!

I want to say that I am personally sorry for all that's happened. We *all* make mistakes from time to time, so it's completely understandable. It's unfortunate that your mistake happened in such a public way, in full view of everyone. We tried our best to soften the blow, but we know it stings no matter what we do.

I think you are a good person, with a good heart. I think we're all lucky to have you here on the site. I hope you will stay and continue to contribute.

I do not think that a first-time offense arising out of poor judgment deserves a suspension, and neither did the rest of the moderator team when we discussed it internally. Therefore, I have to officially mark your "request" for a suspension as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). :-)

The primary reason for suspensions is to educate users and ensure they learn from their mistakes. I think you've been educated, if not downright [tarred and feathered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarring_and_feathering), enough already. I am 100% confident that you have learned from your mistakes, and that you will not repeat them. Therefore, I see no cause whatsoever for a suspension.

Thank you for your apology. I won't try to speak on behalf of the entire community, and definitely not for Zoe or Dharman, but I will say that I *personally* forgive you.

Anyway… Welcome back! As was repeated by multiple commenters where we announced the withdrawal of your nomination, I think we can all agree that the next step is to *forgive and move on*, to put this permanently behind us.

(Also, since you've chosen to speak here, instead of in that withdrawal announcement, I'll be closing and locking that as obsolete.)

Comment: I do think that plagiarism is more serious than "poor judgment" or a "temporary lapse of reason" as it was put somewhere else on meta. Certainly, forgiving Shree is the right thing to do, but this doesn't mean we should forget this happened.

Comment: @idmean You need to look at this from broader context. The whole issue arises because Shree as non native English speaker has huge problems expressing himself. He took other candidate's answers that expressed his point of view and modified them. He obviously felt answering questionnaire was important and this is where "momentarily lapse of reason" comes from. Now, you can say that person that cannot fully express himself might not be the best candidate for mod, but reading and writing are really very different skills.

Comment: Shree also didn't have any reserves admitting he took other answers and this speaks volumes about what kind of person he really is. I can easily forgive and forget his transgression.

Comment: What if I do exactly like this in the next year? -- plagiarize and then sorry. Will I be forgiven like this or is it gonna be a suspension?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes, I get that. But what you do in such a case is cite your source. It wouldn't have been plagiarism if he had stated that his answers were based on Zoe's and Dharman's responses.

Comment: @holydragon People make mistakes. If you learn from your mistakes and other people's mistakes then you can be a better person. In the future it matters whether you have improved or not. If you make same mistake on purpose again, then obviously you haven't learned anything and that is way more serious issue.

Comment: We handle each infraction on a case-by-case basis, @holydragon. My recommendation would be to *assume* that if you plagiarize, you will be suspended. However, it is not guaranteed. (Moderators might, for example, find some mitigating circumstance, like it being a first-time offense.) Regarding forgiveness, it is something that comes *after* punishment. Even if you are suspended for plagiarism, you will be forgiven thereafter, as long as you don't repeat the offense. I feel like my answer spells this out already.

Comment: @idmean The answer says nothing about forgetting. It's up to everyone to either forget it or keep in memory.

Comment: @Cody _"locking that as obsolete"_ Is that a new type of lock that isn't mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228/348196)? I've never seen that before. It _looks like_ a "historical significance" lock (no vote buttons, post buttons, etc.) but the notice's text is different. Do mods have the option to use different notices for that type of lock? If so, we should probably edit [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631/348196) to mention that.

Comment: Adding to what Dalija Prasnikar said, I've made far worse errors in judgement in my life; I've just been lucky that most of them weren't very public so most people don't know about them  People have been making mistakes for thousands of years, and will continue to do so for thousands of years; one of the big problems with the internet is that it's all so darn public and anyone can come in and chide people for their mistakes. So: drama ensues over things that were fairly minor before. I wish people weren't so darn judgemental all the time, or learn that you don't *have* to have an opinion.

Comment: @holydragon This reminds of me of something. The courts found the 1912 sinking of the Titanic to be "an 'act of God'" and no charges were laid. However, they "warned that 'What was a mistake in the case of the Titanic would without doubt be negligence in any similar case in the future.' " https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinking_of_the_Titanic#Public_inquiries_and_legislation

Comment: @41686d6564 Yes, apparently the "obsolete" lock is a new kind of lock that was recently added to the system. I looked briefly on MSE after seeing your comment, but couldn't find an announcement of it or any mention in the "new features" list. But, to be honest, I don't have very much time to spend looking. I can just confirm that I do not remember having this lock type available as an option a few months ago, but it's definitely there now, both on Meta and main. My guess is it's something that we were given as part of the attention being paid to "obsolete answers", but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 89):

I am glad to see you are ok, Shree. We were all worried about you. You have been doing a lot of good work and we hope that you can continue doing it, even without a diamond.

I don't think you deserve a suspension. I can see that you understand your error. What you did was not ok, but I hope that the recent events have given you an important lesson and that you will consider running for a moderator in the future again.

I understand that your English skills are not great. As this election has shown us, even without answering any of the questions in a questionnaire, one might still win. For what's it worth, we wanted to hear your personal opinions and feelings as answers to this questionnaire. Saying nothing at all is sometimes better than saying something wrong.

Please come back to SOBotics and continue your good work on the site.

Thank you for saying I deserve to win. Maybe in the next election, we will win together. :)

Comment: "We will win together" We're hoping !

Comment: They say "third time's the charm" - next time will be the one for you both, do try it out :)

Comment: I agree with _"..even without answering any of the questions in a questionnaire, one might still win"_

Answer (score 54):

Good to see you back Shree!

I will try my best not to re-iterate too much on what has already been chewed-up enough, but I feel like a bit of clearing the air is necessary.

I was the first to comment on [your answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412364/6045800) to the "accusing" meta post. Your follow-up reply-comment to it caused me a great deal of guilt, confusion and many other feelings. I was contemplating for some time whether I should delete that comment, but I decided to leave it mainly because I was *"disappointed"* that you have already did the honorable act of admitting to your mistake, but didn't come clean to the full extent about it.

As I said, I *did* take your reply badly. I didn't mean to accuse you or make you feel attacked and it was hard for me to watch everything that had transpired the following days.

I know you for a long time, mainly from SOCVR interactions, and I witness daily the ***immense*** amount of contributions you make to the site (to anyone unaware, Shree has over 80k (!) helpful flags in 10 years). From here, I can only hope that there are no hard feelings between us and that everything that transpired will not reduce that incredible amount of work you do!

Comment: I think it shows a great deal of compassion and humility on your part to apologize for what in my eyes was a completely legitimate request for further clarification on Shree's answer. I would argue you're the one who is due an apology for the way Shree implied you wrongfully accused him of copying questions 1, 2, and 10. Now it's evident he copied six answers in addition to the one he admitted to, from two more candidates. That reply to your comment demands an apology, to you as well as to the community, for doubling down as to the extent of the offense when called on it.

Answer (score 41):

Shree, I'm also glad to see that you are OK.

It was my question which highlighted the similarities and kicked things off. I'm sorry that I did it in such a public way, and that it led to some negative comments. I realise now that a mod flag would have been more appropriate. My only excuse is that it was very early in the morning for me, and my half-awake brain was genuinely confused by the similarities. I should have thought before posting.

I don't post a lot in Meta, and don't know much about the broader community or individual personalities, but it's clear that you are very well-liked and contribute a lot, so, as others have said, I hope the experience isn't too painful for you, and you consider running again in future.

Answer (score 32):

I was conflicted about whether to upvote the question because I'm glad that you're back or downvote because I don't agree that you deserve to be suspended. Everyone makes mistakes sometimes (I've made more than my fair share), and I certainly don't intend to hold a grudge (and I hope others feel the same way). I for one think you do valuable work for the site and hope you continue to contribute.

Comment: (I'd upvote it if I were you. Otherwise it _might_ seem like you're mad at Shree.)