# Calling up moderators from the 2021 election - welcome, Dharman & Ryan M!

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, moderators, announcement

The mods here on SO have been busily handling the flag pile and keeping their socks matched up - they've also been picking up the tag burninations and other important work that it really helps to have a diamond attached to do.

Because of the increased collection of activities on top of the flagging and some upcoming changes to availability, we're inviting the runners-up from the [last election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13) to join the team.

[image: Dharman]
[image: Ryan M]

They've [joined the existing crew](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) - please give them your help and support as they undertake this new challenge!

Before y'all ask, apologies for releasing this announcement in two phases. The plan has been (from the beginning) to add both to the team and in wanting to get that moving forward, I went ahead with Dharman's announcement while I was waiting on a response from Ryan M. Either way, a big welcome to both of them!

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! Well deserved! Congratulations! I would’ve voted for you in the next election, regardless.

Comment: Congrats Dharman! May your efforts in flagging transition smoothly into efforts in handling those issues directly :-)

Comment: Welcome to the madhouse Dharman. On a sidenote Catija - are socks supposed to be matched up? :p

Comment: Ahh my vote finally worked.

Comment: Congratulations, Dharman! May the diamond be with you

Comment: Dharman, congratulations and well deserved!!

Comment: There is a famous Stack Overflow question about socks: *[How can I pair socks from a pile efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/)* (on par with the [Waldo question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479058/))

Comment: Great use of historical knowledge (past voting results)

Comment: Noooo! This nomination makes the Internet much more insecure. If Dharman spends their time in the flag queues, who's going to point out all the vulnerabilities of SQL injections in newbie's questions?

Comment: @Teemu Just think... it could be you!

Comment: I'm curious, what are the criteria for running a new election vs calling upon a previous runner up? This seems pretty arbitrary to me right now. No problem with Dharman though, I'm sure they will do an excellent job.

Comment: I would say congrats, but let's give it a good 6 months to see if they are truly in order :)

Comment: @DavidG We don't run a new election if the decision to call up new mods is made within 6 months of the previous election. The hard rule is that there must be at least 6 months in-between moderator elections.

Comment: @Teemu Little Bobby Tables wil point them out.

Comment: Congratulations - well deserved :)

Comment: The hero we need. Na-na-na-na-na-na-na-na... Dharman.

Comment: Congrats Dharman!(Where is he though?!)

Comment: @TheMaster Have you seen that pile of trash below? I am in there.

Comment: Finally a mod that can take on the burnination of PHP on its own ...

Comment: Came here to learn why @Dharman suddenly has a diamond next to their name. Very happy to discover this is permanent (i.e., not just a temporary measure to fill in for someone). Those of us who spend time in the review queues are very familiar with @Dharman’s diligence and consistency. Well earned! I’m glad to see my top vote in the last election didn’t go to waste.

Comment: Dharmand .....!

Comment: So, I have to find a new candidate to always vote for...

Comment: Please spend less time on socks and more on the pile of flags :-)

Comment: Now _both_ of my vote-next-time-regardless candidates are moderators! I’m so happy; finally my votes went through!

Comment: And Congrats to Ryan M as well!!

Comment: Not fair, now it looks like I am playing favourites :) Congratulations, RyanM too - was rootjng for ya to make it, and here you are!

Comment: Oh dang, 4 new mods to replace me :p ... J/k .. Good luck Dharman and Ryan. I'm certainly sad that I couldn't get to work with you both in the queues, but I'm sure that you both would do a great job!

Comment: Man! I upvoted when they posted about Dharman, and now since they edited the same post to include Ryan M, I can't upvote it twice!

Comment: Wow, we really will need some new names the next time an election is needed. Hopefully, that won't be for a while. Congratulations to you both!

Comment: Dharman & Ryan M worked so hard for SO, they deserve to be a moderator. On the last election of SO I vote them both, and now I am very very happy to see them as a moderator.

Comment: Dharman's not just moderating SO, he's changing lives. [(reference)](https://www.youtube.com/c/DharMannOfficial)

Comment: Did I comment here about a 4 of 5 candidates being effectively elected rate? That's really not such a bad thing.

Comment: Congratulations @Dharman! Absolutely delighted to see you finally representing the diamond you have long deserved.

Answer (score 88):

Congratulations, Dharman and Ryan! Welcome to the team!

As is something of a tradition, we saved some flags in the flag queue for y'all:

[image: Half of a pile of trash]
<sub>Source: [pixabay.com](https://pixabay.com/photos/disposal-dump-garbage-junk-1846033/)</sub>

Ryan, as it took a bit longer for your diamond to be added, we saved the other half of the flags for you:

[image: The other half of a pile of trash]
<sub>Source: [pixabay.com](https://pixabay.com/photos/disposal-dump-garbage-junk-1846033/)</sub>

Comment: I like the sky color on that one

Comment: Now we know why the flags are not getting handled... @Jean-FrançoisFabre is sitting there staring up at the sky! :-p

Comment: We do everything in the cloud these days!

Comment: According to RyanM, the flag queue now looks like this: https://rimage.gnst.jp/livejapan.com/public/article/detail/a/00/02/a0002380/img/en/a0002380_parts_5b14d8866b12b.jpg?20200929151158&q=80  Well done, moderation team!

Answer (score 57):

Congratulations @Dharman and @RyanM. Stack Overflow has made a wise choice. You both are terrific and level-headed curators. No longer will you need to be concerned with daily limits on your activities. I know that you will both bring great, positive energy to the mod team.

Answer (score 48):

Excellent!

Congratulations to Dharman for a new role. I know you will make it shine.

This is also a great news for Stack Overflow, because there is no such thing as too many moderators here.

Sock puppets beware, your days are numbered.

---

This announcement gets better and better :)

Like I said, there is no such thing as too many mods on SO.

Thumbs up for Ryan M. I can see you have already put your diamond in good use.

Comment: I liked this answer so much that I upvoted it twice. (Oops...)

Answer (score 34):

Since so many participants already extended their welcome to Dharman before Ryan was also on board, let me chime in with

### Welcome Ryan M

and Dharman too of course (-:

Both of you, may your charcoal be red hot!

Comment: +1 for the charcoal gag.

Answer (score 17):

Congratulations Dharman. The mod team and the users just gained a diligent moderator who strives to make the site better.

RyanM I'm also happy you were called up, as time goes by I've realized more and more what a friendly and approachable person you are.

Answer (score 14):

**Congratulations!** I'm very happy to see that Dharman is now a mod!

I see him everyday in review, especially making post edits, and I'm sure it's a good choice. Stack Overflow can only be better with more mods, especially when they are implied.

My (and 17 others) hope from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412612/congratulations-zoe/412629#comment876061_412629) is now live, and that's satisfying.

Comment: What's an "implied moderator"?

Answer (score 13):

Congratulations Dharman! Whenever I looked at your name I was just thinking that it would look much better with a diamond next to it. Now it happened!

Answer (score 11):

I'm really happy with this announcement!

You were both my top picks in the last elections and I was disappointed you didn't make it through. So super excited that my votes didn't go wasted and you got your diamond(s) in the end!

I ***know*** you will both make great mods and wish you a lot of luck with my duplicate answer flags ;)

Answer (score 10):

Congrats Dharman! I was happy to see this because I voted for you in the last election!

Answer (score 9):

Congratulations @Dharman!

I knew that you would be a moderator one day, seeing your diligence in moderating SO with your user privileges. I mean, even with only user privileges, you once offered to help me escalate an issue to the mods yourself!

Well, I guess this means that users running in the next election will have a better chance at getting elected :)

---

Congratulations @RyanM! I'm sure you'll make a great moderator. *(P.S. You were number one on my vote ballot.)*

Comment: `Well, I guess this means that users running in the next election will have a better chance at getting elected` - better chance than 4 elected out of 5 candidates in the 2021 election? It can't get much better than that.

Comment: @Eran Better chance than if two more candidates didn't become moderators, because that would mean two less candidates in the next election.