# Why is there only 1 position open in the 2022 Moderator Election?

Tags: support, moderator-election

I just noticed there's only 1 position open in the [2022 Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/14). This seems to be very few given that it's often said the workload for SO moderators is high and there aren't enough mods. Can someone explain why there's only 1 position open this year?

Comment: Probably because there are already 25 moderators on the site, so we don't really need many more.

Comment: @TheThonnu That's not true. We definitely need more

Comment: My guess is that its because there wont be enough people that nominate

Comment: because there is. What difference does it make?

Comment: They can't afford to pay for any more moderators. With inflation and gas prices being what they are, their use of the Moderator Corporate Jet is enough to break the bank, and let's not get into the plumbing costs for fixing the Executive Bathroom

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine it makes the difference of one more or less mod, if there's a shortage or mods for the workload it seems wasteful to hold an election for just 1 opening.

Comment: Sure, and I would agree _if_ we had an abundance of candidates. The reality is, we don't. Elections have been on a constant decline since more or less the very first one, with that only turning problematic in the last couple years as we nosedive closer to getting under the minimum number of candidates to run an election with two slots. One guaranteed new mod (and yet another probe into interest in the mod position)  is a _lot_ better than no new mods

Comment: Plus, if the bench of alternates i̵s̵n̵'̵t̵ ̵t̵e̵r̵r̵i̵b̵l̵e̵ is high quality, they can always [call up more qualified candidates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416887/calling-up-moderators-from-the-2021-election-welcome-dharman-ryan-m).

Comment: I think we should just be thankful that elections happen with relative frequency.  This gives those with diamond aspirations hope to be bejeweled while they are enthusiastic.  If we want to "scare more nominees out from their bunkers", I can try self-nominating!

Comment: Being a moderator is highly esteemed among the community. But if it's given to many, it dilutes existing value(just like inflation). While workload is a factor to be considered, the rate of growth in moderator size should be proportional to site growth.

Comment: @TheMaster actually no, the only thing having more mods dilutes is rarity. If they're good at being a mod any addition is a plus. Value here is getting things done expediently and well.

Comment: @TheMaster:  This is actually a false distinction. With enough reputation, one already is a moderator.  Diamond moderators just get access to a lot more sensitive data and can do deeper drives into other kinds of bad behavior that mere mortals can't.  While having some folks handle that niche side of moderation is essential, there's still *plenty* that people north of even 3K rep can do to help moderate stuff.

Comment: Let me flip the question to make my point. Why are(or should) we not accepting all eligible candidates, who have successfully answered all questions, as moderators? Surely, that will reduce the workload. Right?

Comment: Because there's PII involved.

Comment: @TheMaster see TylerH's answer he addresses that question.

Comment: Moderators get paid in flags anyway. "Hey I cleared 100 flags!"  "Excellent job, here are 200 flags as your reward".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There were only two spots open in last year's election, but they ended up adding four moderators from that election, ultimately.

After this election is over, I suspect they will probably call up the 2nd and maybe also 3rd place candidates, eventually, even with only one spot officially available in the election.

If I had to guess, I'd say they don't have the bandwidth to train that many new moderators at once... onboarding a new moderator takes a lot of effort from the CMs and the current mod team, as I recall hearing. And each new moderator probably takes more effort to onboard than previous moderators as the site grows larger and the features more complex.

Answer (score 14):

Honestly I wouldn't worry about it too much.  If the need is greater than the initial scheduling, then a candidate could be called up after the election.

Zoe does make a good point about the decline in interested candidates, though.  Supposing that we have a landfall of users who are interested in doing this, *then* it'd make sense to open up a few more.

Comment: So, you're running for mod then?

Comment: I'd have to be an interested candidate first, @rene ‍

Comment: Consider it though, since you would make an excellent one

Comment: I disagree. Someone not willing is absolutely not an excellent candidate. And being not willing should be perfectly acceptable.