# Calling up more moderators - Is this a new trend?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

This happened two elections in a row now:

- [Calling up moderators from the 2021 election - welcome, Dharman & Ryan M!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416887/13552470)
- [2022 Community Moderator Election Results - now with two more mods!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421619/13552470)

*<sub>Congrats and thanks to the extra volunteers, by the way!</sub>*

Should we consider this a new trend?

Or are we going to open more slots in our elections in the future?

Comment: They keep calling up instead of more slots is because they (SO staff and mods) are not sure if there would be enough canidates

Comment: It does give me more chances to brag about though, "never happened when I was a mod" :p

Comment: _"Should we consider this a new trend?"_ Why does that even matter? What is a "trend", even?

Comment: 2 subsequent occurrences never makes a trend. 3 would be starting to look more like it... but on Stack Overflow you can find patterns in just about anything you look at and its still all just coincidental.

Comment: Also probably not a coincidence that this happened at the same time as a veteran moderator stepped down.

Answer (score 18):

No, this is a *very* common thing that happens.

Irrespective of how many open slots are open during election, if the moderator team needs more people then they call more people up from the last election.